# @Viewbag gives null value the first time used

Tags: c#, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc

ok, the problem is I am trying to take a value from a view with `<form method=" post">` , then take it to the controller and do some math operations on it, and then resend it to the view with Tempdata. the problem is, the first time I try to use it, I get a null value, but when the site reloads, the second time I get the value of the last value I entered:

controller:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Home_Page(FormCollection frm)
{
    int firstnumber = Convert.ToInt32(frm["firstnumber"]);
    int secondnumber = Convert.ToInt32(frm["secondnumber"]);
    TempData["secondnumber"] = secondnumber;
    TempData.Keep();
    //int differenceresult = firstnumber - secondnumber;
    //int sumresult = firstnumber + secondnumber;
    //ViewBag.differenceresult = differenceresult;
    //ViewBag.sumresult = sumresult;

    return View();
}
```

view:

```js
$("#btnsum").click(function () {
    alert(@Html.Encode(@TempData["secondnumber"]))
})
```

can anyone help me???

Comment: It looks like you place TempData value only in HttpPost action, but first time page rendered by HttpGet. Could you please set brakepoints in both of them and check, what action used for first and for second time.

Answer (score 0):

The first time you load your page, it will trigger an Action Verb which is `HttpGet` on your Action Method `Home_Page`. In other words, you need an `HttpGet` Action Method so that when you trigger your `HttpPost` which you posted on your code above, it will properly declare your TempData variable. Here is an example I can provide for you:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Home_Page()
{
  int firstnumber = Convert.ToInt32(frm["firstnumber"]);
  int secondnumber = Convert.ToInt32(frm["secondnumber"]);
  TempData["secondnumber"] = secondnumber;
  TempData.Keep();
  return View();
}
```

If both of your actions have the same name, but different Action Verbs (HttpGet, HttpPost), then they must have different parameter declarations so that it will not be considered ambiguous by the compiler. So in this case, on my example, I don't have any parameters declared.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I tried what you said. but this time the first value I get is 0, and any value after that gives null